# segmentation fault: 11, extracting data in vector

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to write a program with opencv and C++. I have an image and I am trying to get the saturation value of determined pixel which is in the (x, y) point. I use the next sentence to do it:

```
saturation_level = hsv_chanels[1].at<uchar>(x, y);
```

The thing is that the program builds OK, but when I try to run, it sometimes works fine and sometimes terminates with this error:

Segmentation fault: 11

Do someone know why this error is appearing? I read that this error appears because of the my computer memory but I don't know why it only appears sometimes.

EDIT:

This is the function I call to find the homography:

```
Mat ObtenHomografiaSuelo (vector <KeyPoint> keypoints1, vector <KeyPoint> keypoints2, Mat imagen1, Mat imagen2){
    //*****************************************************************************
    //Find homography mat
    //*****************************************************************************
    vector < Point2f > image_points[2];
    int cont = 0;

    vector<Mat> chanels_hsv1;    //[0]->H, [1]->S, [2]->V
    split( image1, chanels_hsv1 );
    vector<Mat> chanels_hsv2;
    split( image2, chanels_hsv2 );


    for(vector<KeyPoint>::const_iterator it = keypoints1.begin(); it!= keypoints1.end(); ++it){
        // Get the position of left keypoints
        float x = (it->pt.x);
        float y = (it->pt.y);

        cout << "1" << endl;
        float saturation_level = chanels_hsv1[1].at<uchar>(x, y);
        cout << "2" << endl;
        double max_level = 70.0;
        cout << "3" << endl;
        if ((y < camSize.height/4) && (saturatio_level < max_level) ){
            cout << "1:" << endl;
            waitKey (100);
            cout << "y: " << y;
            cout << "         Saturation_Level: " << nivel_saturacion << endl;
            image_points[0].push_back(Point2f(x,y));
            cout << "done" << endl;
            cont ++;
        }

    }

    cont = 0;
    for (vector<KeyPoint>::const_iterator it = keypoints2.begin(); it!=keypoints2.end(); ++it) {
        // Get the position of left keypoints
        float x = (it->pt.x);
        float y = (it->pt.y);
        float saturation_level = chanels_hsv2[1].at<uchar>(x, y);
        double max_level = 70.0;

        if ((y < (camSize.height)/4) && (saturation_level < max_level)){
            cout << "2" << endl;
            waitKey (100);
            cout << "y: " << y;
            cout << "         Saturation_Level: " << nivel_saturacion << endl;
            image_points[1].push_back(Point2f(x,y));
            cont ++;
        }
    }
    cout << "We are obtain: " << cont << " points to do the homography" << endl;
    waitKey();


    Mat H;
    H = Mat::zeros(4, 4, CV_64F);
    if (cont < 4) {
        cout << "Few points to do the homography" << endl;
    }
    else{
        if (image_points[0].size() > image_points[1].size()){
            image_points[0].resize(image_points[1].size());
        }
        else if (image_points[1].size() > image_points[0].size()){
            image_points[1].resize(image_points[0].size());
        }

        H = findHomography (image_points[0], image_points[1], CV_RANSAC, 3);
        cout << "done_matrix" << endl;

    }

    return H;
}
```

Before to call the function I detect keypoints using Harris or any other detector and the image I passed to the function is a HSV_image converted by cvtColor function.

The error appears in the line that I mentioned before because in the terminal I can se:

1

Segmentation Fault: 11

Comment: You need to provide more code than that.

Comment: This looks like *undefined behavior.* Perhaps `hsv_chanels` does not have two elements; perhaps the second element does not have the element you seek. It is impossible to know without seeing more code.

Comment: Questions for you:  Is hsv_chanels a local variable, or passed in by reference?  If by reference, it may help to print the address of hsv_chanels before it is used, in case it somehow came as zero.  Can you also print the value of x and y before the crash?

Comment: Do you have an unbounded array operation overwriting the stack?

Comment: `The thing is that the program builds OK, but when I try to run`  Just because a program "builds ok" doesn't mean it will run ok.  The former just proves that the program is syntactically correct, and all of the function calls have been resolved.  It has no bearing on whether there are logic or other bugs in your code.

Comment: Please see the edit text.  About the donjuedo question: I declared here this variables as you can see in the edit. Another detail, I'm using a stereo par cameras.

Comment: I'm sorry because my english is not very good. I tried to explain by the best way that I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I've just finished to correct the error, I think it was because I wasn't using efficiently my function. I was using two 'for' staments to cross my two vectors of keypoints detected and the errors sometimes appears at first and others at second one. I don't really know why was the error, I just change my code to do the same think more efficiently and finally it works.

I just changed this lines:

```
for(vector<KeyPoint>::const_iterator it = keypoints1.begin(); it!= keypoints1.end(); ++it){
        // Get the position of left keypoints
        float x = (it->pt.x);
        float y = (it->pt.y);

        cout << "1" << endl;
        float saturation_level = chanels_hsv1[1].at<uchar>(x, y);
        cout << "2" << endl;
        double max_level = 70.0;
        cout << "3" << endl;
        if ((y < camSize.height/4) && (saturatio_level < max_level) ){
            cout << "1:" << endl;
            waitKey (100);
            cout << "y: " << y;
            cout << "         Saturation_Level: " << nivel_saturacion << endl;
            image_points[0].push_back(Point2f(x,y));
            cout << "done" << endl;
            cont ++;
        }
cont = 0;
    for (vector<KeyPoint>::const_iterator it = keypoints2.begin(); it!=keypoints2.end(); ++it) {
        // Get the position of left keypoints
        float x = (it->pt.x);
        float y = (it->pt.y);
        float saturation_level = chanels_hsv2[1].at<uchar>(x, y);
        double max_level = 70.0;

        if ((y < (camSize.height)/4) && (saturation_level < max_level)){
            cout << "2" << endl;
            waitKey (100);
            cout << "y: " << y;
            cout << "         Saturation_Level: " << nivel_saturacion << endl;
            image_points[1].push_back(Point2f(x,y));
            cont ++;
        }
    }
```

by this ones:

```
for (int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++) {
        int idx1=good_matches[i].queryIdx;
        int idx2=good_matches[i].trainIdx;
        if (((keypoints[0][idx1].pt.y < (camSize.height/4)) && (canales_hsv1[1].at<uchar>(keypoints[0][idx1].pt.x, keypoints[0][idx1].pt.y) < nivel_maximo)) || ((keypoints[1][idx2].pt.y < (camSize.height/4)) && (canales_hsv2[1].at<uchar>(keypoints[1][idx1].pt.x, keypoints[1][idx2].pt.y) < nivel_maximo)) ) {
            cout << "entro" << endl;
            matched_points[0].push_back(keypoints[0][idx1].pt);
            matched_points[1].push_back(keypoints[1][idx2].pt);
            contador ++;
        }
    }
```

Currently I only cross the matched keypoints instead of all the keypoints, it requires less computers operations and  now it works OK.

Comment: row, col world ! it has to be :  `chanels_hsv2[1].at<uchar>(y, x)`

Comment: You are right, the order of coordenates need to be change.